# Using an Arduino to Emulate a CD4021 Shift Register for Controlling an NES

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, shift-register, hobbyist

This is probably a silly thing to do when I could wait for my CD4021s (74HC165Ns) to arrive and save myself the hassle but I feel as though this can be done and I'm simply missing something. I've pored over all of the documentation I can find on the web about the NES's controller protocol and how to emulate an 8-bit parallel-in, serial-out shift register but I just can't seem to get it to work correctly. I'm using interrupts on the latch and clock signals from the NES and pumping out the bits using port manipulation so it's a bit ugly. This is also my first time writing anything similar. I may just be getting the timing wrong.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong? Here's some documentation on the NES protocol: http://www.mit.edu/~tarvizo/nes-controller.html, and the SNES protocol: http://www.repairfaq.org/REPAIR/F_SNES.html (more detailed but slightly different - not sure which to trust).

Here's my code as it is now:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define plPin PIND
#define latchPin 2
#define latchShift 2
#define dataPort PORTB
#define dataPin 8
#define dataShift 0
#define dataMask (B00000001 << dataShift)

byte origButtons = B11111111; // Set each bit low (0) to push button.
volatile byte buttons;
volatile byte bit_num = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(latchPin, INPUT);
  dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | (B00000000 << dataShift);
  attachInterrupt(0, latch, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(1, pulse, RISING);
  delay(1);
}

void loop() {

}

void latch() {
  // Check the state of the latch pin to see if we're rising (1) or falling (0).
  if ((plPin & (1 << latchShift)) != 0) {
    // Start pulled high.
    dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | (B00000001 << dataShift);
  } else {
    // Pull low if A button is pressed at fall of latch pulse.
    dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | ((buttons >> bit_num) & B00000001) << dataShift;
    bit_num++;
  }
}

void pulse() {
  // On the rising edge of the clock pulse, check for the state of the next button.
  // If the button is pressed, pull (or stay) low. Otherwise, pull high.
  //
  // Bit Math
  // --------------
  // Example values:
  // dataPort: 11111111
  // buttons: 11001100 (1 = HIGH/not pressed - 0 = LOW/pressed)
  // bit_num: 3
  // Reverse the dataMask (result: 11111011).
  // AND that result to the current value of dataPort (result: 11111011).
  // Shift buttons to the right by bit_num (result: 00011001).
  // AND 00000001 to that result so the least significant digit is the value of the current button (result: 00000001).
  // Shift that result by the data pin's position (result: 00000100).
  // OR that with the result from ANDing the reverse of the data mask and the current value of dataPort - see 4 lines up (result: 11111111).
  // Final result: button 3 not pressed.
  if (bit_num == 7) {
    // On the last pulse in a sequence, spit out the last button, wait until it has been sampled by the CPU, and reset the pin to the default low.
    dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | ((buttons >> bit_num) & B00000001) << dataShift;
    delayMicroseconds(12);
    dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | (B00000000 << dataShift);
    bit_num = 0;
  } else {
    // Otherwise, just spit out the current button and increment the offset.
    dataPort = (dataPort & ~dataMask) | ((buttons >> bit_num) & B00000001) << dataShift;
    bit_num++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use SPI slave mode, so that the hardware does the heavy lifting?

Comment: I had considered it, I just couldn't wrap my head around it given Arduino's documentation. Couldn't find a good tutorial on using it as a slave that would respond to pulses either.

Comment: Yeah... forget the Arduino stuff. Go to [the source](http://www.atmel.com/).

Comment: [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=10892&reply=1#reply1) is an article with an example of Arduino SPI-Slave. Where it uses Interrupts. From the Latch's ISR you could pre-load the SPDR that would get slave shifted out and then the SPI's ISR after shifting could pre-load the next SPDR.

Comment: mpflaga: Thanks for the advice and link to the article. However, my problem is that the Arduino would be creating it's own SPI clock signal as it reads out the data. The issue is that I need it to read out the data, bit-by-bit, using the clock signal sent to it by the NES. This is how the shift-register in the controller works.

Comment: Nothing in your code suggests that it's using SCK as an output.

Comment: About the above code and whats wrong with it. Put some prints in it and walk it slowly through the sequence. Honestly that is a lot of bit math to follow on discrete ports. Most all Arduino users simplify things with the digitalRead and digitalWrite, that abstract all that port and bit stuff out of view. You could also simulate and scope it on 123circuits or other Arduino Simulator.

Comment: Why are you left-shifting 0 in a couple of places?

Comment: in your code I see you pinMode(dataPin, output) but never see dataPin actually output'ed. I wonder if you have dataPort and buttons backwards. Where it appears that dataPort(portb) is the 8bit parallel input and buttons is the latch of it. but you appear to be writing out to dataPort, not shifting it out dataPin.

Comment: In Gammons reply #1 referenced above there are two examples Master and Corresponding Slave. The later code's SS and SCK are inputs along with the MISO and MOSI, being SO and SI. Where the SCK and miSO will mimic the 74HC165N and 4021, as desired. Note the default state of all pins are INPUT. And Gammon's example discretely (w/o library) init's the SPCR with only enabling it for the ISR. Hence the SS, SCK and MOSI are input. so that when SS is low the SPDR value will be shifted out when SCK is toggled.

Comment: mpflaga: It has to use bit math to be fast enough to react to the NES's signals. Thanks for the sites to simulate things, though.

dataPin is part of PORTB. I just didn't want to use DDRB to set all of the pins when I only needed to set one.

Thanks for pointing out the example that I need. I may also have found a way to do it using this interrupt-based code, but I'll try both and find out which works.

Comment: Except this is for an 8-bit shift register using an NES instead of a 16-bit using an SNES.

Answer (score 1):

The following will compile. And should do what the Slave SPI as discussed above:
It is note worthy that on a UNO w/328 that much of the byte wide ports don't have all 8 pins available.

```
// Note that Port B has the SPI and Port D has the UART so start testing with C[0..5]
// where C[6,7] will likely be zero. Once working then later move to Port D which has
// all 8 bits, but without any debug on the uart.
void setup (void)
{
  pinMode(MISO, OUTPUT); // have to send on master in, *slave out*
  SPCR |= _BV(SPE);      // turn on SPI in slave mode
  SPCR |= _BV(SPIE);     // turn on interrupts
  attachInterrupt(0, latch, FALLING); //pin 2 on UNO, could be other modes...
  // may need to tweak the SPI mode to match chips. Something for later
}  // end of setup

void latch() {
  SPDR = PINC; // grab Port C input and place it for upcoming shift.
}

// SPI interrupt routine
ISR (SPI_STC_vect)
{
  // ISR will occur after 8 bit shift out of prior contents of SPDR 
  // by Master SCLK with SS low
  SPDR = SPDR; // read moSI and write it out on next miSO for cascading.
}  // end of interrupt service routine (ISR) SPI_STC_vect

void loop (void)
{
  // don't really need to do anything.
}  // end of loop
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it over here, but for SNES (16 bits). The exact same code will work for NES, as the NES will only read the first 8 bits. [Does anyone have code to emulate a 16-bit input shift register with an ATtiny2313?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/does-anyone-have-code-to-emulate-a-16-bit-input-shift-register-with-an-attiny231)